# Showing a timer on through a QLabel inside QDialog box

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qt4

I am making a small GUI application where I was made a pop-up dialog box which prompts the user to press OK or CANCEL. If user presses OK, some changes are saved and if user presses CANCEL the changes are discarded.

Now, I am thinking to put a timer in the dialog box, inside a QLabel object,which will show like this--

[image]

Sending message in 5 secs,
Sending message in 4 secs,
..
..
Sending message in 1 secs.

And after the countdown is done default "OK" will be considered and all changes will be saved.
How to achieve such a visual effect on GUI applications ?? I mean implementing a concole timer is easy enough but how to visualize a timer through GUI screen ??? any helps..

Comment: You create a `QTimer` and connect its `timeout()` signal to a slot updating the label text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in constructor:

```
mutable int sec = 5;//in header for example, we need mutable to use it in lambda 
//...
ui->label->setText("Sending message in 5 secs");
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this,[=]() {
    sec--;
    if(!sec)
    {
        qDebug()<< "Ok";
        timer->stop();//stop timer and do something
        //Ok
    }
    else
        ui->label->setText(QString("Sending message in %1 secs").arg(sec));
   });
    timer->start(1000);
```

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.

For `Qt4`:

```
ui->label->setText("Sending message in 5 secs");
timer = new QTimer(this);//class member
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(slot())); 
timer->start(1000);
```

In slot:

```
sec--;
if(!sec)
{
    qDebug()<< "Ok";
    timer->stop();//stop timer and do something
    //Ok
}
else
    ui->label->setText(QString("Sending message in %1 secs").arg(sec));
```

And `sec` variable can be not mutable